# How to get all the polygons that fall within a bounding box in GeoJson?

Tags: python, geojson

I have a geojson covering a whole city and I need to get the Information of certain polygons that are within a bounding box.

The issue is I have several areas around the city, and what I'm doing right now is looping over all the polygons to determine if they fall within the bounding box for each of my bounding boxes.

my code looks like this for each bounding box:

```
window_x_min, window_x_max = wx-d, wx+d
window_y_min, window_y_max = wy-d, wy+d


# iterate over the parcels
for i, feature in enumerate(geojson['features']):

    polygon = feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0]
    y1, x1 = pixel_conversion( *polygon[0], ds )

    # chacking if polygon is in the box
    if window_x_min <= x1 <= window_x_max and window_y_min <= y1 <= window_y_max:
           Store the polygon.....
```

Is there a more efficient way?